# How to deserialize a message into a strongly typed object, then dynamically call a runtime-assigned handler for that message

Tags: c#, deserialization, message-queue, messagebroker

Phew, what a title...

I am working on a server for a learning project. I've spent quite some time trying to figure out how to frame this question properly. In the beginning, I don't think I even knew exactly what I was trying to achieve.

What I am working with is a server that has N components (N >= 0).

- Each component is added at runtime using DI.
- Each component is a "black box". When it receives a message, it is considered a "unit of work" and has everything it needs to go from start to finish.
- Each component is responsible for providing info for `subscribing` to a `message`, and providing a `handler` for that message. I plan to achieve this using an attribute on the `handler` function.

An example of a "handler":

```
[Handles(ExampleMessage)]
private void handleExampleMessage(ExampleMessage message)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

This is the clearest way I can think of framing my question:

How can I achieve a *typed* "message broker" system like how ASP.NET MVC provides *typed* models to a `controller` `action` from a *serialized* input.

So what I'd like to achieve is:

`Serialized message` -> `Strongly typed message` -> `message service` -> `call handler function with *strongly typed* message as an argument`

I thought of a few things:

First thing I tried was simply de-serializing the message to a `dynamic`, but not having inellisense and compile-time checking is too high a cost for the simplicity of `dynamic` for me.

Then I tried creating static de-serialization methods at runtime using reflection, and using the return value from those to call the "handlers", but it got *so ugly* and spaghetti, I just had to drop it (although I am of course still open to this option if someone has an elegant, performance conscious way)

Finally I tried using a `Message` type that all messages inherit from, but I end up getting stuck when I try to use a `Dictionary<Action<Message>, Message>` to call the appropriate handlers

Comment: If your message is json, for example, it contains no meta-info. So you'd need your components to provide a method to handle their own deserialisation, or at least return a boolean to say if the object is of their supplied type or not.

Comment: @monty Good point, I should have mentioned that I am using MessagePack for .net. The messages are classes, so when they are de-serialized, (`Serializer.Deserialize<TMessage>(byte[] data)`) the metadata is inferred by the Type.

Comment: so you already have the ability to deserialise the incoming data into the correct type?

Comment: @monty I do, it requires creating run-time deserializer methods using reflection, as I mentioned, but it's do-able. I decided to add an identifier to the serialized messages and keep a `Dictionary<Id, Type>` to keep track of their types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, and only a little bit complicated. What you'll want to do is search your components for methods that have your `Handles` attribute, and call them via reflection.

Let's assume we have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IComponent
{
}

public interface IMessage
{
};
```

Let's also create the `Handles` attribute that will let us tag methods as handling a specific message type:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class HandlesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type MessageType { get; private set; }

    public HandlesAttribute(Type messageType)
    {
        MessageType = messageType;
    }
};
```

Now we'll create a message broker which will be responsible for finding all message handling methods in a given list of components. We'll use reflection to do this. First we'll find all methods that have the `Handles` attribute, and then we'll check if they have the required single `IMessage` parameter:

```
public class MessageBroker
{
    // Encapsulates a target object and a method to call on that object.
    // This is essentially our own version of a delegate that doesn't require
    // us to explicitly name the type of the arguments the method takes.
    private class Handler
    {
        public IComponent Component;
        public MethodInfo Method;
    };

    private Dictionary<Type, List<Handler>> m_messageHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, List<Handler>>();

    public MessageBroker(List<IComponent> components)
    {
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            var componentType = component.GetType();

            // Get all private and public methods.
            var methods = componentType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (var method in methods)
            {
                // If this method doesn't have the Handles attribute then ignore it.
                var handlesAttributes = (HandlesAttribute[])method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HandlesAttribute), false);
                if (handlesAttributes.Length != 1)
                    continue;

                // The method must have only one argument.
                var parameters = method.GetParameters();
                if (parameters.Length != 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method {0} has too many arguments", method.Name));
                    continue;
                }

                // That one argument must be derived from IMessage.
                if (!typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(parameters[0].ParameterType))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method {0} does not have an IMessage as an argument", method.Name));
                    continue;
                }

                // Success, so register!
                RegisterHandler(handlesAttributes[0].MessageType, component, method);
            }
        }
    }

    // Register methodInfo on component as a handler for messageType messages.
    private void RegisterHandler(Type messageType, IComponent component, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        List<Handler> handlers = null;
        if (!m_messageHandlers.TryGetValue(messageType, out handlers))
        {
            // If there are no handlers attached to this message type, create a new list.
            handlers = new List<Handler>();
            m_messageHandlers[messageType] = handlers;
        }

        var handler = new Handler() { Component = component, Method = methodInfo };
        handlers.Add(handler);
    }
}
```

The constructor above logs a warning message and ignores any methods that don't match the signature that we require (i.e. one parameter which derives from IMessage).

Now let's add a method to handle a message. This will call any registered handlers using `Invoke`:

```
    // Passes the given message to all registered handlers that are capable of handling this message.
    public void HandleMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        List<Handler> handlers = null;
        var messageType = message.GetType();
        if (m_messageHandlers.TryGetValue(messageType, out handlers))
        {
            foreach (var handler in handlers)
            {
                var target = handler.Component;
                var methodInfo = handler.Method;

                // Invoke the method directly and pass in the method object.
                // Note that this assumes that the target method takes only one parameter of type IMessage.
                methodInfo.Invoke(target, new object[] { message });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("No handler found for message of type {0}", messageType.FullName));
        }
    }
};
```

And now to test it we'll use these example messages and component. I've added some misconfigured methods for testing as well (i.e. wrong parameters):

```
public class ExampleMessageA : IMessage
{
};

public class ExampleMessageB : IMessage
{
};

public class ExampleComponent : IComponent
{
    [Handles(typeof(ExampleMessageA))]
    public void HandleMessageA(ExampleMessageA message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Handling message of type ExampleMessageA: {0}", message.GetType().FullName));
    }

    [Handles(typeof(ExampleMessageB))]
    public void HandleMessageB(ExampleMessageB message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Handling message of type ExampleMessageB: {0}", message.GetType().FullName));
    }

    [Handles(typeof(ExampleMessageA))]
    public void HandleMessageA_WrongType(object foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HandleMessageA_WrongType: {0}", foo.GetType().FullName));
    }

    [Handles(typeof(ExampleMessageA))]
    public void HandleMessageA_MultipleArgs(object foo, object bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("HandleMessageA_WrongType: {0}", foo.GetType().FullName));
    }
}
```

And finally to bring it all together:

```
var components = new List<IComponent>() { new ExampleComponent() };
var messageBroker = new MessageBroker(components);

// A message has been received and deserialised into the correct type.
// For prototyping here we will just instantiate it.
var messageA = new ExampleMessageA();
messageBroker.HandleMessage(messageA);

var messageB = new ExampleMessageB();
messageBroker.HandleMessage(messageB);
```

You should get the following output:

```
Method HandleMessageA_WrongType does not have an IMessage as an argument
Method HandleMessageA_MultipleArgs has too many arguments
Handling message of type ExampleMessageA: Program+ExampleMessageA
Handling message of type ExampleMessageB: Program+ExampleMessageB
```

Full fiddle that you can play with is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ehngb1).

To improve method call performance you could rewrite the `MethodInfo.Invoke` using the techniques mentioned [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/).

Comment: I like the approach, but in my case, the messages are handled by individual methods I.E. a component can have any number of handlers that handle any number of *different* messages. I'll try to see if I can adapt your solution.

Comment: Sure thing, I created a new [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J98Ser) to include an example of that. I also refactored the message handler dictionary into a `MessageBroker` class.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart then each component would have multiple classes that implement an IHandler (instead of IComponent) interface

Comment: @Sam see  now that solution is very elegant, the *only* thing I'd like to add is for the handlers to received *typed* messages, as in *not* just the interface, but the underlying type. Obviously, I could just cast the message in the handler, but I'd rather not if possible. Can you think of a way to integrate that into this method? If not, I think I can live with this solution as-is, it's quite elegant.

Comment: I wrote up another [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LsbrLM) that is more in line with your original question (i.e. using the attributes to define the methods, and multiple methods handling messages in a component). Let me have a think about how passing in the actual concrete type could work.

Comment: @Sam I had something similar, although nowhere near as elegant as what you propose, but I too got stuck on getting the concrete type into the method without explicitly casting. It's why I mentioned ASP.NET's way of going from a serialized model to a strongly typed one, although I'd be willing to bet it's at the expense of efficiency...

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Alright check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ehngb1) out! It's a bit more complicated now. It lets you put the actual type in the method signature, and it will display a warning message if the method has more than one parameter, or the parameter is not an `IMessage`. The key is to call the method via the `MethodInfo` object. You could even go one step further and get rid of the `Handles` attribute entirely and just scan for methods that take an `IMessage`-derived type.

Comment: This seems to do *exactly* what I was hoping for. I like how the `reflection` is done *once*, it won't affect performance while the app is running. I'm just curious about the overhead of calling `MethodInfo.Invoke()`, is there any downside to this method?

Comment: I haven't profiled it at all, but my understanding from a quick search is that `MethodInfo.Invoke` is slower than calling a method directly or even via a `Delegate` instance. I'm not totally sure how to get around that in this case though. You *might* be able to use [`DynamicMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate the method call at runtime. But if this solves your problems right now, I would just roll with it and profile it later if there are perf issues. It shouldn't be too hard to retrofit a solution.

Comment: I'll rewrite my answer using the last fiddle then since it more accurately answers your question!

Comment: Related: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/

Comment: One year later, I'm reading over this and I realised that we don't even need to specify the `MessageType` in the `HandlesAttribute`; we can infer it from the method argument. I can't believe I didn't think of that earlier. It seems so obvious! Here's an updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dymxtH